# How to parse a json object sent in Body(Request)

Tags: swift, vapor

```
func createPoll(on req: Request) throws -> String {
   let poll = try req.content.decode(Poll.self)

   return poll.save(on: req).map(to: Poll.self) {
      return poll
   }
}
```

This works only of the Data is sent under a json Object

```
{
  "title": "Once Poll",
  "option1": "Black finish",
  "option2": "Dark Gray finish",
  "votes1": 10,
  "votes2": 0
}
```

But I can't parse the object if it is sent like this with a key: poll!

```
{
  "poll": {
    "title": "Once Poll",
    "option1": "Black finish",
    "option2": "Dark Gray finish",
    "votes1": 10,
    "votes2": 0
  }
}
```

This is the solution I used using the answer below:

```
struct PollRequestObject: Content {
let poll: Poll?
```

}

```
 func createPoll(on req: Request) throws -> Future<Poll> {
        guard let poll = try req.content.decode(PollRequestObject.self).poll else {
            throw Abort(.badRequest)
        }

        return poll.save(on: req).map(to: Poll.self) {
            return poll
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Vapor how your request looks with a `PollRequestData` object which would look like:

```
struct PollRequestData: Content {
  let poll: Poll
}
```

Your decode then looks like: `let poll = try req.content.decode(PollRequestData.self).poll`

Comment: I don't understand why the struct is PollRequestObject and the decode has PollRequestData.self ?!

Comment: That’s a very good question! Apparently I can’t spell or wasn’t concentrating! Have fixed it

Comment: how would you convert a string into the same type as req.content. Basically, I am using a WebSocket and the socket is receiving data as a string and I need to convert that into JSON using content/codable. how would I go from string to content?